# 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total' me devuelve 0 ¿por qué?

Tags: mysql, sql

pues lo dicho en el titulo. La función siempre devuelve 0, sin embargo en localhost (xampp) funciona perfectamente. A $post_por_pagina le he hecho un echo y está bien. Muchas Gracias!

```
function numero_paginas($post_por_pagina, $conexion){
$statement = $conexion->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total');
$resultado = $statement->fetch()['total'];

return ceil($resultado / $post_por_pagina);
```

}

Comment: Para usar `FOUND_ROWS()` primero tiene que haber una consulta previa, como dice el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows). ¿Estás usando PDO o MySQLi?

Comment: Hola de nuevo @A. Cedano, esta función la tengo en funciones.php y la llamo desde paginacion.php. En index.php tengo la llamada a funciones (entre ellas la conexión PDO), config, header y paginacion.         La verdad es que una cosa que no me había dado cuenta es que tengo varias tablas en la data base, quizá debería especificar que me refiero a la tabla 'articulos'. Pero no sé cómo....     Mil gracias

Comment: Mira el ejemplo que pone el Manual (enlace de mi comentario anterior). `FOUND_ROWS()` lo que hace es devolver el número total de filas que traería una consulta en la cual se ha usado `LIMIT`, o sea, si se quiere saber cuántas filas tiene la tabla en realidad (sin `LIMIT`).  Para que funcione, tiene que haber una consulta previa parecida a esta: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM persona LIMIT 1`, una consulta normal, pero que incluya `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Luego de esa consulta entonces puedes ejecutar: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total`

Comment: Perdóname @A.Cedano pero no sé cómo realizar dos consultas en php. He hecho esto pero me da error, me dice que total no está definido:<br/>                                         function numero_paginas($post_por_pagina, $conexion){
    $statement = $conexion->query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM articulos; SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total');
    $resultado = $statement->fetch()['total'];
    
    return ceil($resultado / $post_por_pagina);
}

Comment: Tienes que hacer primero esta consulta: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM articulos;` y manejar los resultados que traiga puesto que si la haces es porque necesitas esos datos (supongo). Y luego que hayas traído y usado esos datos, entonces puedes lanzar la otra consulta, algo así: `$total = $conexion->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();` y tendrás en `$total` la cantidad de filas que tiene la tabla `articulos`. Aunque no veo claro qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente ¿? ¿Algo así como calcular un promedio?

Comment: no, solo quiero obtener todas las filas de la tabla

Comment: Para obtener todas las filas de la tabla puedes hacer algo como esto: `$total = $conexion->query('SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM articulos')->fetchColumn();` y tendrás en `$total` la cantidad de filas de esa tabla. Como dice el Manual, `FOUND_ROWS()` actúa en combinación con consultas limitadas...

Comment: @A.Cedano, eres mi salvador!   discúlpame pero mis conocimientos en db son muy básicos, quiero ponerme al día pero primero me gustaría afianzar mis conoxcimientos de PHP      Mil gracias!!!!!

Comment: Voy a escribir una respuesta, explicando de paso cómo funciona `FOUND_ROWS()` y para qué sirve, por su puede ser de utilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente `FOUND_ROWS()` sirve para saber cuántas filas tiene una tabla sobre la que previamente hemos hecho una consulta que incluya `LIMIT`. Además, esa consulta previa debe tener dentro  `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

El [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) lo explica con toda claridad:

> Una instrucción `SELECT` puede incluir una cláusula `LIMIT` para
>   restringir el número de filas que el servidor devuelve al cliente. En
>   algunos casos, es deseable saber cuántas filas habría devuelto la
>   instrucción sin el `LIMIT`, pero sin volver a ejecutar la instrucción.
>   Para obtener este recuento de filas, incluya una opción
>   `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` en la instrucción `SELECT`, y luego invoque
>   `FOUND_ROWS()`:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECCIONE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
>     -> WHERE id> 100 LIMIT 10;
> mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS ();
> ```
>
> El segundo `SELECT` devuelve un número que indica cuántas filas habría
>   devuelto el primer `SELECT` si se hubiera escrito sin la cláusula
>   `LIMIT`.
>
> En ausencia de la opción `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` en la declaración
>   `SELECT` exitosa más reciente, `FOUND_ROWS()` devuelve el número de
>   filas en el conjunto de resultados devuelto por esa declaración. Si la
>   declaración incluye una cláusula `LIMIT`, `FOUND_ROWS()` devuelve el
>   número de filas hasta el límite. Por ejemplo, `FOUND_ROWS()` devuelve
>   10 o 60, respectivamente, si la declaración incluye `LIMIT 10` o
>   `LIMIT 50, 10`.
>
> El recuento de filas disponible a través de `FOUND_ROWS()` es
>   transitorio y no se pretende que esté disponible más allá de la
>   instrucción que sigue a la instrucción `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.
>   Si necesita consultar el valor más adelante, guárdelo:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ...;
> mysql> SET @rows = FOUND_ROWS ();
> ```
>
> Si está utilizando `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, MySQL debe calcular
>   cuántas filas hay en el conjunto de resultados completo. Sin embargo,
>   esto es más rápido que ejecutar la consulta de nuevo sin LIMIT, porque
>   el conjunto de resultados no necesita enviarse al cliente.
>
> `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` y `FOUND_ROWS()` pueden ser útiles en
>   situaciones en las que desea restringir el número de filas que
>   devuelve una consulta, pero también determina el número de filas en el
>   conjunto de resultados completo sin volver a ejecutar la consulta. Un
>   ejemplo es un script web que presenta una visualización paginada que
>   contiene enlaces a las páginas que muestran otras secciones de un
>   resultado de búsqueda. El uso de `FOUND_ROWS()` le permite determinar
>   cuántas otras páginas se necesitan para el resto del resultado.

Como se puede deducir de lo dicho anteriormente, `FOUND_ROWS()` funciona con una consulta previa que ha sido limitada.

En tu contexto, el uso de `FOUND_ROWS()` sería algo parecido a esto:

```
$stmt = $conexion->query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM articulos LIMIT 5');
/*
   1. Obtener los datos de la consulta limitada para su uso
   2. Lanzar una nueva consulta para saber el total de filas sin LIMIT
*/
$total = $conexion->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();
```

Ahí tendrás en `$total` la cantidad de filas de `articulos`.

Ahora bien, si no hay consulta previa y lo que se quiere es conocer el número de  filas de una tabla, lo más natural es usar `COUNT()`.

```
$total = $conexion->query('SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM articulos')->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que generes dos sentencias independientes con `COUNT(*)` ya que `FOUND_ROWS()` quedará obsoleta desde la versión **MySQL 8.0.17**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id > 100;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM users WHERE user_id;
```

Adicionalmente, según la documentación, informan mejor rendimiento.